# Splits of (entire) words in C++

Tags: c++, string, text, split

Let's suppose that we have a text which has to be processed by a set of workers (mappers in a map/reduce project): each portion of the text (split) has to be consistent (no word can be splitted between two workers) and the size of the splits should be equal as possible (load balancing).

**Here's my algorithm:**

1. Divide the text in equals splits, each one composed by `off_t begin` and `off_t end` (starting and ending byte inside the text).
2. Make each split consistent: if the split ends in the middle of a word, jump to the next white space (and do the same with the begin). Without this phase the result may be wrong: think about the famous "word count" example in map/reduce.

**Input (text length = 29 chars):**

`Hello Darkness my old friend`

**Phase 1 with 4 Workers (~= 7 chars per worker):**

`|Hello D|arkness| my old| friend|`

**Phase 2:**

`|Hello Darkness| |my old |friend|`

**This is the code of Phase 2 for each split:**

```
        ifstream ifs (file , ifstream::in);
        char c;
        string s;
        if(begin>0){//begin=0 then first split: cannot break a word!
            //if char before the first one is different from ' ' or '\n'
            //then the split begins in the middle of a word (bad)
            ifs.seekg(begin-1,ios::beg);
            ifs.get(c);
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n'){
                getline(ifs,s,' '); //jump to the next white space
                begin+=s.length();
            }
            if(begin>end)
                end=begin;
        }
        ifs.seekg(end,ios::beg);
        ifs.get(c);
        if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && end != size){
            getline(ifs,s,' ');
            end+=s.length();
        }
```

As you can see, this solution has two problems:

1. Splits size may be unbalanced (look the first and the second splits!)
2. The code is a little bit tricky

Have you any suggestion to improve the solution (in term of elegance and/or performance)?

Comment: Here is one shot: forget at all about phase 2 at that moment! I explain: just divide into equal parts, process all this parts, and in a third phase, check that the words where broken and combine the last one of one worker with the first one of the next worker. Also, to help in this third phase, the workers could record if they have started/finished with space or not

Comment: Cannot do that! As you can see in the update, the workers are mappers in a Map/Reduce project. If you know the famous "word count" example, then you know that you cannot split a word between two workers! Anyway my lack of problem description, sorry for that!

Comment: Would I be wrong in saying that you are simply trying to do a multi threaded word count. Or something similar, perhaps converting the fstream to a vector of words. Also do the workers share memory as would a traditional multi-threaded situation or are you deploying to a cluster of machines???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that algorithmically, you can't do much better (and if you are doing Map|Reduce you presumably have *lots* of data so the difference will be small).  The work of arranging the split as `Hello| Darkness| my old| friend` is going to be excessive.

A slight improvement might be:

- Estimate where the first split should be (character 7 in this case)
- Read to it.
- Look forward *and back* for the closest space.
- Split on that.
- If you have searched back, then you already have the start of the next chunk in your hand.
- Update your estimate of how long the next chunk should be.
- Loop

The only trouble is that this is going to make the code even *more* complex.

Comment: This solution has another problem: it introduce a state between iterations, which means no "parallel loop" (the result of an iteration depends on the previous one). Btw thanks for your answer, it would be good for serial execution!

Answer (score 0):

You could check backwards as well and use the side which has less chars until the space. However, this would result in additional complexity. For this simple case it does not matter much, because I'd expect that such small parts will be processed so fast that there will not be any noticeable difference.

And with the raising size of the split (say 500 chars or even a megabyte), if the words will keep relatively short, the unbalances will become less and less important - so I wouldn't bother either and I would "keep it simple, stupid" (KISS).