# Array of pointer correct only if printed?

Tags: c++

The function is used to split a text in different (possibly balanced) chunks (I've talked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287397/splits-of-entire-words-in-c) in details). Here's the code (look below it for problem description):

```
pair<off_t,off_t>* getSplits() {
    struct stat st;
    off_t size;
    if (stat(file_name.c_str(), &st) == 0)
        size = st.st_size;
    int nMappers = size > nWorkers ? nWorkers : size; //if workers are greater than file size
    pair<off_t,off_t> splits [nMappers];
    double split_size = (double) size / nMappers;
    off_t acc = 0 ;
    ff::ParallelFor pf( ff_realNumCores() );

    string prova = file_name;
    pf.parallel_for(0,nMappers,[&splits,split_size, prova, size](const long i) {
        ifstream ifs (prova , ifstream::in);
        off_t begin = ceil((double) i*split_size);
        off_t end = ceil((double) (i+1)*split_size-1);
        char c;
        string s;
        if(begin>0){
            //if char before the first one is different from ' ' or '\n'
            //then the split begins in the middle of a word (bad)
            ifs.seekg(begin-1,ios::beg);
            ifs.get(c);
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n'){
                getline(ifs,s,' ');
                begin+=s.length();
            }
            if(begin>end)
                end=begin;
        }
        ifs.seekg(end,ios::beg);
        ifs.get(c);
        if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && end != size){
            getline(ifs,s,' ');
            end+=s.length();
        }
        splits[i] = {begin, end};
    });
    pair<off_t,off_t> *p = splits;
    for(int i=0;i<nWorkers;i++){
        cout<<"begin="<<p[i].first<<" end="<<splits[i].second<<endl;
    }
    return p;
}
```

And this is the way that I call it and print it its content:

```
pair<off_t,off_t> *splits = input_format->getSplits();
for(int i=0; i<nWorkers; i++){
    cout<<"outside split begin="<<splits[i].first<<" second="<<splits[i].second<<endl;
    this->ff_send_out(new MapTask<MIK,MIV,MOK,MOV> (record_reader->clone(),splits[i],map_func));
}
```

The problem is that if I print `p`'s content inside `getSplits()` (the last `for` cycle), then the result is correct:

```
begin=0 end=13
begin=14 end=14
begin=15 end=21
begin=22 end=28
outside split begin=0 second=13
outside split begin=14 second=14
outside split begin=15 second=21
outside split begin=22 second=28
```

**BUT** if I do not (so I delete the printing `for`), then the result is wrong (only the first pair is correct)!

```
outside split begin=0 second=13
outside split begin=140152066182136 second=140152054622976
outside split begin=140152066227112 second=29521758
outside split begin=140152054622960 second=2564825869
```

How this is possible?

Comment: You're returning a dangling pointer, undefined behaviour.

Comment: BTW, You use VLA which is an extension.

Comment: As pointed by others, you are returning a dangling pointer, try reading this for more understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475635/returning-pointer-to-a-local-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return address of a local variable, so you have dangling pointer.

I suggest to return `std::vector<std::pair<off_t, off_t>` instead.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use a `vector` since it's space inefficient and I already know the exact number of elements (so a static array is a better choice).

Comment: @justHelloWorld: Your size is not known at compile time, so you cannot use array (except if you use the maximum size, but you will loose more space than for `vector` in general case). Moreover, vector can be moved whereas `std::array` is copied. a static array forbid you to call the method twice...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your reply, but what I meant is that from what I know `vector` is space inefficient because if it doubles its space whenever the previous allocated space is filled, while a fixed size array (like `new pair<off_t,off_t> [nWorkers]`) is space efficient since allocates the needed (and no more) amount of space.

Comment: I understood the fact that `vector` has `capacity` member... You may manage capacity size with `reserve` and `shrink_to_fit`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a pointer to the stack (which is where your function defined splits).

Use global/static vars, or better off, pass the pointer array and fill it inside the function.